# Accepting only numbers in C++ program without the if else statement

Tags: c++

I made a simple program where users can vote. Here I've truncated the actual code so other users don't have to waste their time. As you can see the while loop isn't working but the program works with if else statement. I'm also commenting out my own understanding of program
so you can point out anything I'm doing wrong here. Note that I've tried all the loops and I don't know why it doesn't work. Sorry for being noob and yes I appreciate your effort to answer my question, yesterday the site went to read only mode so I couldn't update nor comment here. Anyway, here is my code

**Here is my program, I'm having problem with:**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>

    int main (void)

    {
        int pollVote = 0;
        std::string pollVoteString;

        do
        {
            std::cout << "Enter your vote: \n";
            getline (std::cin, pollVoteString, '\n');
            std::stringstream verifyPoll(pollVoteString);

        while (!(verifyPoll >> pollVote && verifyPoll.eof())) // To accept only numbers :)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid number entered! Try again.\n";
            getline (std::cin, pollVoteString, '\n');

        }

        } while (!(pollVote > 0 && pollVote < 4));

        std::cout << "Thanks for voting!\n";
    }
```

**Here is my working program using if else:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main (void)

{
    int pollVote = 0;                     //setting to 0 to make the do while loop work
    std::string pollVoteString;           // creating a new string

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter your vote: \n";           //asking user to enter a vote
        getline (std::cin, pollVoteString, '\n');    // saving the input as string
                                                     // in "pollVoteString" variable

            while (true)                   // starting infinite loop
        {
            //the stringstream will create a new variable called verifyPoll
            //and read data from "pollVoteString" and save it in "verifyPoll"

            std::stringstream verifyPoll(pollVoteString);


            // if "verifyPoll" can insert data to "pollVote" 
            // and "verifyPoll" don't have more than one data type then it will break.

            if (verifyPoll >> pollVote && verifyPoll.eof()) 
            {
                break; // Success :D
            }
           //otherwise ask the user to enter the vote again.
           else
            {
                std::cout << "Invalid number! Try again.\n";
                getline (std::cin, pollVoteString, '\n');
            }
        }

    } while (!(pollVote > 0 && pollVote < 4));    //Making sure that the vote is 1,2 or 3.

    std::cout << "Thanks for voting!\n";          //checking the exit from the loop.
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting all the code? Why not a snippet to describe the problem?

Comment: @EdHeal the actual code is much bigger, I'm posting just my custom function code.

Comment: `for (;verifyPoll >> pollVote && verifyPoll.eof();)`  why isn't this just a while loop `while(verifyPoll >> pollVote && verifyPoll.eof())`

Comment: In the `for` loop, you are redefining `verifyPoll`.

Comment: you have 2 `std::stringstream verifyPoll`, the second shallow the first one.

Comment: @FelixCastor at first I tried while loop but it didn't worked so I tried for loop but no success. It should work but it's not.

Comment: @Amession - can you not narrow down the code further. People on this web site are not prepared to look through realms of code. Nearlly 100 lines of it

Comment: @Jarod42 it won't reach at the second std::stringstream verifyPoll if the condition isn't satisfied but compiler is not even looking at the loop.

Comment: You should already have constructed a [testcase](http://sscce.org) in order to do your debugging, _days_ before resorting to asking here. And I'm getting really bored of saying this.

Comment: @Amession: Did you even read Jarod's comment? Of course the compiler is "looking at the loop" (it doesn't magically ignore loops and I'm not sure why you keep thinking that it does), so the only other possibility is that your loop condition is broken. Focus on that for two minutes and you'll see that you're checking the wrong `verifyPoll`, because you shadowed it inside the loop body. You have two `verifyPoll`s.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "days before resorting to asking here." - exactly. Exactly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit testcase? sure, I'll keep in mind next time. FYI I'm noob at C++ and I learned about stringstream today and wanted to try it out, spent 3 hours debugging code, finally posted here if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong when using the loop.

Comment: @Amession: Keep it in mind _this time_ and edit it into your question.

Comment: @Amession - Bear in mind people on this forum like to do people a favour. So try to make it easy for them.

Comment: @EdHeal yes, I appreciate that, the code is updated, I couldn't do anything yesterday because the site went to read only mode, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inverted the sense of your test. Your `for` loop can be written as this `while` loop:

```
while (verifyPoll >> pollVote && verifyPoll.eof()) {
    // ...
}
```

What you want is

```
while (!(verifyPoll >> pollVote && verifyPoll.eof())) {
}
```

Also, you must not declare a new `verifyPoll` within the loop body, because now if the first answer does not validate, the loop will not terminate. You might instead assign a new string using

```
verifyPoll.str(pollVoteString);
```

but you should do it after the `getline`.

Comment: check my updated code, I did as you said but still no success. And I also tried do while, for and while loops. 
And you said verifyPoll.str(pollVoteString); should be after the getline which makes the loop to cause errors because the variables in condition won't be identified, I think it's almost impossible to do this in a loop.

Comment: @Amession You're missing the very important `verifyPoll.str(pollVoteString);` after the `getline` in your loop. `stringstream` copies the string passed to it, so when you change the original string you are not updating the stream.